# Can't get Django CreateView to save

Tags: django, django-views

No doubt I'm missing something obvious here...

urls.py

```
url(r'^screening_add/$', ScreeningCreate.as_view(), name="screening_add"),
```

views.py

```
class ScreeningCreate(CreateView):
    model = Screening

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(ScreeningCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

screening_form.html

```
<form action="." method="post"> {{ form }}{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This puts up the form with the Screening fields but on submit nothing happens. I have a breakpoint at the return statement in form_valid and it doesn't get executed. Removing the dot in action has no effect. What the heck am I missing?

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript that could stop the request from bring submitted?

Comment: Have you tried outputting `form.errors`?

Comment: Re JavaScript, yes I have some but nothing that would interfere with a submission. Nevertheless, I removed it and no change in behavior.

Comment: Further narrowing down, I removed the name param from the url. Of course it made no difference. One odd thing. Note that in the HTML I use form without any as_p or whatever. When I do a GET it comes up in table format, when I submit, ie, POST, it comes up in P format. Kinda odd...

Comment: Bingo meshy! Yes I have left a few required fields blank. And form.errors has shown me my knuckleheadedness. And here I thought I didn't make errors. Thanks.

Comment: One last note. I guess I expected it to get to the breakpoint in form_valid but apparently this error checking happens prior to that and prevents the submission. Who's doing that? Is that client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Is this is your whole views.py? It should like this:

```
class ScreeningCreate(CreateView):
    model = Screening
    form_class = ScreeningForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(ScreeningCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Well, I actually do have a form and all that good stuff but I commented it all out in order to isolate the problem. So no, the code I have shown here works as described. Or doesn't work, I should say.